How to extract text Data from Images and Structuring it into an Excel Table
I'm extracting JSON data which provides the following result. The data includes coordinates with the text retrieved from the picture. Is there a way to identify a table and store that data in Excel?
This data was extracted using jaded AI's EasyOCR. I need to convert the data to a table format where it fits. Additionally, EasyOCR doesn't accept PDFs. Is there a method to convert PDFs to PNG?
result = [
    [[[1395, 95], [1557, 95], [1557, 137], [1395, 137]], 'Nst'],
    [[[663, 197], [779, 197], [779, 239], [663, 239]], 'COPY'],
    [[[200, 248], [586, 248], [586, 394], [200, 394]], 'TOM CHRIS LDSAY Ardmore Search Partners 4US'],
    [[[1004, 248], [1369, 248], [1369, 485], [1004, 485]], 'COMMERCIAL CARDS DIVISION Cards Customer Services PO BOX 5000 SOUTHEND-ON-SEA SP2 9AM Telephone: 1243 673 3701 Facsimile: 1234 789 5281 Monday Friday: 08.00 18.00 Saturday: 09.00 13.00'],
    [[[210, 596], [544, 596], [544, 628], [210, 628]], '06 February 05 March 2024'],
    # And so on...
]

I attempted to use the following approach with openpyxl:
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for item in result:
    bounding_box = item[0]  # Bounding box coordinates
    text = item[1]  # Text content

    # Determine row and column based on bounding box coordinates
    # For simplicity, let's assume each bounding box represents a row
    row = bounding_box[0][1]  # Y-coordinate of the top-left corner
    column = bounding_box[0][0]  # X-coordinate of the top-left corner

    # Write text to the corresponding cell in the worksheet
    ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value = text
wb.save("output.xlsx")


It doesn't make sense to write the text at the cell location of the TLC or whichever which means the text values will appear in different places all over the Sheet.
You mention you want to put the data into a table. Then why not do that?
This can be done just dump the data into a table layout on the Sheet.
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Alignment
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter as gcl

result = [
    [[[1395, 95], [1557, 95], [1557, 137], [1395, 137]], 'Nst'],
    [[[663, 197], [779, 197], [779, 239], [663, 239]], 'COPY'],
    [[[200, 248], [586, 248], [586, 394], [200, 394]], 'TOM CHRIS LDSAY Ardmore Search Partners 4US'],
    [[[1004, 248], [1369, 248], [1369, 485], [1004, 485]], 'COMMERCIAL CARDS DIVISION Cards Customer Services PO BOX 5000 SOUTHEND-ON-SEA SP2 9AM Telephone: 1243 673 3701 Facsimile: 1234 789 5281 Monday Friday: 08.00 18.00 Saturday: 09.00 13.00'],
    [[[210, 596], [544, 596], [544, 628], [210, 628]], '06 February 05 March 2024'],
    # And so on...
]


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

### Add some headers to the tabulated data
## Two rows merged 1st row, 2nd row for X and Y co-ord header
headers = [['Bottom Left', '', 'Top Left', '', 'Top Right', '', 'Bottom Right', '', 'Text'],
           ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y']
]
for header in headers:  # Append the headers to the Sheet (first row)
    ws.append(header)

## Merge the first row common columns
merges = ['A1:B1', 'C1:D1', 'E1:F1', 'G1:H1', 'I1:I2']
for merge in merges:
    ws.merge_cells(merge)

### Set some formatting for the Headers, bold and align middle and top
for row in ws.iter_rows(max_row=2):
    for cell in row:
        cell.font = Font(bold=True)
        cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='top')

### Flatten the list of lists for each row of data then append to the Sheet
for item in result:
    flattened_list = [ele for group in item[0] for ele in group]
    flattened_list.append(item[1])
    ws.append(flattened_list)  # each row is appended below the last added row

### Set some column widths
for col in range(1, 9):
    ws.column_dimensions[gcl(col)].width = 8

### Save Excel file
wb.save("tabulated.xlsx")

Not sure the naming for the co-ordinates are correct way around so you can change these as necessary


Thank you so much for your answer. however I want only text in excel based on co-ordinates of the result.  ex. if in top left corner there two text vertically alligned then in excel it should be respecttively in cell A1 and A2

Do not know what that means. Some co-ordinates need to match then you want to put only the text from the matched image in to cells A1 and A2??? You need to be clearer about what your question is. I don't see how the comment reflects what the Posted questions is asking.
